# Covariant form of a tensor.

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors

I understand why stress-energy tensor for a comoving observer at rest relative to the fluid is

diag$\{\rho, -P,-P,-P\}$

How does this lead to the generalized covariant form, often quoted in textbooks as

$$T^\mu{}_\nu=(\rho+P)U^\mu U_\nu-P\delta^\mu{}_\nu$$
?

Thanks.

Comment: Think of what the velocity $U$ means in terms of reference frames...